# dnn 7.0 platform 500 internal server error

Tags: dotnetnuke, web-platform-installer, web-platforms

im trying to install DNN platform on windows 8 via web platform installer but i keep getting the following error:
this product did not download successfully. the remote server returned an error: (500) internal server error.

can anyone tell me what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend doing a manual installation of DNN. The web platform installer can have problems, and when it does, tracking them down is rather difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a few issues with Web platform installer trying to install Joomla CMS where it constantly fails midway. For DNN, I always do it manually which is not too hard. If you chose this option, find [instructions here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Install_DotNetNuke) and [even better instructions here if you want to to be able to access the db with Sql Server Management Studio](http://www.scribd.com/doc/168845934/Dotnetnuke-DNN-Database-setup-Instructions) for development purposes. Check out the [system requirements here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Platform/Start/Install#2047) for different versions of DNN